# How do I avoid recursively adding arrays when I need to merge two arrays in a while-loop?

Tags: python, arrays, while-loop, pygame

Working with pygame, I am trying to create a larger list out of two smaller lists. This needs to be done during the game loop because those lists contain `pygame.Rect` objects which determine collision detection with the character.

```
charArray.append(guy.rect)
collideArray = newMap.rectArray + charArray
```

Of course, since this is in the game loop, `guy.rect` is recursively added to `charArray`, and `collideArray` is recursively adding `newMap.rectArray` to itself, creating a larger and larger list every frame, which eventually just destroys the framerate.

Is there a way I could empty the lists every frame so that they are simply being redefined every frame? Or is there some other approach I need to be taking?

Comment: When you say "recursively", you mean "in a loop", or is there recursion involved somewhere?  Also, will `newMap.rectArray` change in the loop or is it fixed?

Comment: newMap.rectArray will change in the loop when a new area needs to be drawn. Same with guy.rect (guy being a non-player character). When I say it's recursive, I mean the array keeps on being added onto itself. The output of print(len(collideArray)) increases every frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to "empty" every array at the end of each frame is just to set them as empty at the end of each loop:

```
while game==True:
    #your game code goes here
    charArray,collideArray = [],[]
```

Comment: I thought that might work too, but it doesn't seem to be emptying the arrays (maybe just re-initialising them?), resulting in the same thing. I've tried putting this both before and after the two lines I've got in the question

Comment: is `guy.rect` recursive so that it adds them all anyways?

Comment: guy.rect contains a single pygame.Rect object. Output of print(guy.rect) is <rect(258, 298, 16, 16)>

Comment: Figured it out, it was that newMap.rectArray was recursive

Comment: there you go haha, glad I could help